# Can not check if an array is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the folloiwng action method inside my asp.net mvc application:-

```
 public ActionResult CustomersDetails(long[] SelectRight)
        {

            if (SelectRight == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
                RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                var selectedCustomers = new SelectedCustomers
                {
                    Info = SelectRight.Select(GetAccount)
                };




                return View(selectedCustomers);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

But if the `SelectRight Array` is empty then it will bypass the `if (SelectRight == null)` check and it will render the CustomerDetails view and raise an exception on the following code inside the view

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Info) {
    <tr>
```

So how can i make the null check works fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to **return** the result of `RedirectToAction(..)`.

```
 public ActionResult CustomersDetails(long[] SelectRight)
 {
      if (SelectRight == null)
      {
           ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      else
      {
           '...
```

Answer (score 8):

You can change the condition to the following one:

```
...
if (SelectRight == null || SelectRight.Length == 0)
...
```

That should help.

**EDIT**

The important thing to note about the code above is that in c#, the or operator `||` is short circuiting. It sees that the array is null (statement is true) and does NOT attempt to evaluate the second statement (`SelectRight.Length == 0`) so no NPE is thrown.

Comment: It will still break, since if it's null, it'll do a `RedirectToAction("Index");` and still render the View. Kaboom.

Comment: From the above description it looks like an exception is thrown on CustomerDetails view: "and it will render the CustomerDetails view and raise an exception"

Comment: The description says a foreach breaks, a foreach won't break on an empty array, but on a null collection.

Comment: You are right Joachim. However, if you check the code, you can see that for empty `SelectRight`, the assignment `Info = SelectRight.Select(GetAccount)` will probably assign null value to Info. Then `@foreach (var item in Model.Info)` will throw an error (as `Info` if null). So checking if the array is null or empty makes sense.

Comment: Well, `IEnumerable.Select` on an empty collection won't return null but another empty collection. The problem is that when `SelectRight` _is_ null, it won't assign `Info` at all but instead call `RedirectToAction("Index");` (more or less a no-op without returning the value) and fall through to `return View();` which will render the CustomerDetails view without setting `Info` at all. Of course all bets on return values are off if the `Select` called is a user implemented function and not the Linq one :)

Comment: As you pointed out, it is difficult to give good answer without access to entire source code. But it is always a pleasure to have constructive conversations :)

Answer (score 4):

You could check that it isn't null, and doesn't have a length of zero.

```
if (SelectRight == null || SelectRight.Length == 0) {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes...");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Above if-statement would catch both null-values and empty arrays.